# How to prove $f\in \mathbb R[x]$ and $\deg(f)\geq 3$ then $f$ is reducible?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to prove $f\in \mathbb R[x]$ and $f$ is irreducible then $\deg(f)\leq 2$.

By Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, $g\in \mathbb C[x]$ and $g$ is irreducible then $\deg(g)\leq 1$

I tried to use the fact $\dim_{\mathbb R}\mathbb C=2$ but I couldn't solve this problem. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ has a real root, then $p(x)$ is clearly reducible over $\mathbb{R}$.

Otherwise, note that if $z$ is a non-real root of a polynomial $p(x)$, then the complex conjugate $z^*$ is also a non-real root of $p(x)$. What can you say about the polynomial $(x - z)(x - z^*)$?